# Warning message or redirect in voting system

Tags: laravel

my voting system is incomplete and I am having difficulty showing a warning or otherwise redirect to the login page for unregistered users. In my controller I wrote that only the registered user can vote otherwise redirect, but it doesn't work, it doesn't just put the vote by freezing. How can I make a redirect or show a modal alert?

Javascript

```
$(document).on('click','#saveLikeDislike',function(){
        var _post=$(this).data('post');
        var _type=$(this).data('type');
        var vm=$(this);
        // Run Ajax
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ url('save-likedislike') }}",
            type:"post",
            dataType:'json',
            data:{
                post:_post,
                type:_type,
                _token:"{{ csrf_token() }}"
            },
            beforeSend:function(){
                vm.addClass('disabled');
            },
            success:function(res){
                if(res.bool==true){
                    vm.removeClass('disabled').addClass('active');
                    vm.removeAttr('id');
                    var _prevCount=$("."+_type+"-"+_post+"").text();
                    _prevCount++;
                    $("."+_type+"-"+_post+"").text(_prevCount);
                } 
                
                if(res.bool==false){
                    vm.removeClass('active').addClass('disabled');
                    vm.removeAttr('id');
                    var _prevCount=$("."+_type+"-"+_post+"").text();
                    _prevCount--;
                    $("."+_type+"-"+_post+"").text(_prevCount);
                }
            }   
        });
    });
    // End
```

Controller

```
// Save Like Or dislike
function save_likedislike(Request $request){
    
    if($request->post == null){
        abort(404);
    }
    
    $checkItem = DB::table('items')->where('id', $request->post)->first();
    if($checkItem == null){
        abort(404);
    }
    
    $check = DB::table('like_dislikes')
        ->where('item_id', $request->post)
        ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
        ->get();
    
    $total = DB::table('like_dislikes')
        ->where('item_id', $request->post)
        ->count();
    
    if($check->count() < 1){
        $data = new LikeDislike;
        $data->user_id = Auth::id();
        $data->item_id = $request->post;
        if($request->type == 'like'){
            $data->like=1;
        }else{
            $data->dislike=1;
        }
        
        if($data->save()){
            return response()->json([
                'bool'=>true
            ]);
        }
        
    } else {
        
        DB::table('like_dislikes')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('item_id', $request->post)->delete();
        return response()->json([
            'bool'=>false
        ]);
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a middleware to check if user is authenticated or not?

Comment: Hi, I did, but still nothing.